# Ant absolute path to single file in fileset

Tags: ant, jenkins, absolute-path, fileset, email-ext

I'm using Jenkins with Email-Ext plugin to automate PHP Unit Testing. If the tests failed I want to send a notification email to myself including the zipped test reports.

The Email-Ext plugin requires an Ant Fileset definition in the attachment field. 
The zipped test report can be found here:

```
D:\Test_Reports\test-report-failed.zip
```

I can't find a working example of the use of `fileset` with absolute path to a single file.

I tried the following but didn't work:

`<fileset file="D:\Test_Reports\test-report-failed.zip" />`

Could find any example of using absolute paths but relative paths only.

This is the official help from the Email-ext plugin about the attachment field:

`This is the set of attachments that will be used for the email. The format is a comma separated list of Ant include file syntax. The base directory is the workspace.`

Comment: Then reference them relative to the workspace, not with an absolute path.

Comment: The workspace can be different and is located in another drive. I have to use absolute paths somehow.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I solved it by changing the Jenkins Job's workspace to the directory where are the test reports and other resources located. Then I was using relative addressing to the zip file like: `test-report-failed.zip`

Comment: this isn't helpful to anyone else

Answer (score 3):

You can use `<include/>` tag to do this. It will look like this.

```
<fileset dir="D:\Test_Reports">
    <include name="test-report-failed.zip" />
</fileset>
```

If you want to get file path in property then you can do this in that way (I've tested this and it works):

```
<path id="absolute.path.id">
    <fileset dir="D:\Test_Reports">
        <include name="test-report-failed.zip" />
    </fileset>
</path>
<property name="absolute.path" value="${toString:absolute.path.id}" />
<echo>file absolute path: ${absolute.path}</echo>
```

Comment: I believe I should specify the include syntax only. But I guess it is not possible to use absolute path in the include statement.

Comment: I've edited my answer. You can use `<path/>` task to get absolute path.

Answer (score 0):

Just specify the absolute path of your file in the attachment field (not the XML element).